# How to filter data in a query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, filter, google-bigquery

This query is for a project at work, I need it to filter and return the "quantity" of a specific word like "workers" within this dataset of my work . I'm new to this and need to know how to filter this value efficiently

```
SELECT 
     lines.accounting_book_id      AS Livro
    ,lines.book_name               AS Nome_Livro
    ,lines.period_name             AS Periodo
    ,lines.effective_period_num    AS Num_Periodo  
    ,lines.company_code AS Empresa
    ,lines.brand_code AS Bandeira
    ,lines.product_code AS Produto
    ,lines.account_unit AS Conta_Contabil
    ,lines.account_name_ptb AS Descri_Conta_Contabil
    ,lines.cost_center AS Centro_Custo
    ,lines.intercompany_code AS Intercompany
    ,lines.business_unit AS Unidade_Negocio
    ,lines.future_code AS Futuro2
    ,lines.accounting_date AS Data_Contabil
    ,lines.posted_date AS Data_Postada
    ,lines.currency_code AS Moeda
    ,lines.line_description AS Descri_Linha
    ,lines.batch_name AS Journal_Batch
    ,lines.header_name AS Journal_Entry
    ,lines.supplier AS Fornecedor
    ,lines.item AS Item
    ,lines.period_num AS Mes
    ,lines.created_by AS Criado_Por
    ,lines.line_num AS Num_Lin
    ,lines.posted_by AS Postado_Por
    ,lines.initial_balance AS Saldo_Inicial
    ,lines.entered_debit AS Total_Debito
    ,lines.entered_credit AS Total_Credito
    ,lines.accounted_debit AS Total_Debito_Conv
    ,lines.accounted_credit AS Total_Credito_Conv
    ,lines.final_balance AS Saldo_Final
    ,lines.dre_classification AS Class_DRE
    ,lines.dre6 AS DRE

FROM `my_project` lines
WHERE lines.chart_of_accounts_id  = "ID_account"
AND CAST (lines.accounting_date AS string) LIKE '2022-12%'
```

I already ran it in the bigquery and it just returned everything that had inside the dataset from December, because is it very basic.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS(lines.book_name, r".*workers.*") AS contains_word
```

then `count` a column that does not have any blanks and `group` by `contains_word` you would have to do this for each column.

Someone else may have a more efficient method